# Delete database column from "select" statement using mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have the following code, that shows all the books I have in my books table.

```
<select id="booksToDelete">
    <?php
        foreach($bookTitles as $bookTitle) {
        echo '<option>';
        echo $bookTitle['Title'];
        echo '</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>

<input type="submit" name="deleteBook" id="deleteBook" value="Delete Book" />
    <?php
```

I want to be able to delete the any book, based on the option selected by the user on the html page, but I'm not sure how to finish it. This is what I have so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteBook']))
        $deleteQuery= 'DELETE FROM book WHERE Title=**I don't know what goes here**;
    ?>
```

Please help!!

Comment: The title goes in the quotes, but a "title" is not unique, you should be using IDs. You also should parameterize the query when you put the title/ID in. If the question is how to put a value in an option you need to add the attribute `value`.

Answer (score 0):

As chris85 has pointed out in the comment section, you should be using `ID`s to determine what to delete in your table. Using `title` would result of multiple deletion if in case there are books having the same exact title.

Lets fix your `option` tags. We will use `value` attribute to put the `ID` as values instead and not the `title`. Lets also use `name` attribute for your `select` field.

This is inside a `form` tag right?

```
<form method="POST" action=""> <!-- PUT THE PAGE WHERE YOU WILL PROCESS THE REQUEST TO THE ACTION ATTRIBUTE -->
    <select name="booksToDelete" id="booksToDelete">
<?php
    foreach($bookTitles as $bookTitle) {
        echo '<option value="'.$bookTitle['id'].'">'; /** REPLACE CORRESPONDING INDEX WITH THE UNIQUE ID COLUMN OF THE book TABLE **/
        echo $bookTitle['Title'];
        echo '</option>';
    }
?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="deleteBook" id="deleteBook" value="Delete Book" />
</form>
```

Then once submitted. By the way, what mysql API are you using to connect to your database or to execute queries? For this example, lets use [`mysqli_*`'s prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

```
/** ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION **/
$con = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database"); /** REPLACE NECESSARY DATA **/

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['deleteBook'])){

    $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM book WHERE id = ?"; /** REPLACE NECESSARY UNIQUE ID COLUMN **/
    /*                                      ^       */

    $stmt = $con->prepare($deleteQuery);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["booksToDelete"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

}
```